# Red Error Screen when build first project in React

Tags: react-native

Today I start to learn about React. After install React by some command in Terminal, I use react-native MyFirstProject to create my first project, and in my Android Studio emulator get a red error screen like this:

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M4ey.png)

I tried to resolve follow there command but still have no idea what I am doing? Can someone explain for me how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Answer (score 1):

To fix open a new terminal,go to your project folder and run

> npm install

after installation complete

> npm start

What **“npm start”** does is start your react package manager, read more about it in details here

> https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm

Also run the command,
This is quite a useful tool during development.

> adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

And last Reload.

> For android one can use **CTRL + R** For apple one can use **R + R (two
>   times R).**

Answer (score 0):

Looks you didn't install babel, babel module is not existion the the node_module.

`npm install babel` then `npm start`
If it doesn't work. You can try `npm start --reset-cache`

Hope it help.